# Compare Date C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#

How can I compare Date ([now] day, month, year, hour, minute) and data from two columns? The first column has date only like "2020-01-01" and second column for same row has data like "15:30:00" and this column datatype is `time7`.

I need to check if ([now] day, month, year, hour, minute) > from this two columns to do something.

[image: this is data from data base]

I need to compare it in client side in C#

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected results.

Comment: date column         time column                                                                                              ----------------    ||  --------------------                                                                                               2020-01-01     ||   15:50:00                                                                                                   this data in Data Base                                                                          i need when i check now like   2020-04-08 00:36:00 then date in database less do something

Comment: Actual examples of real data from your database please.

Comment: Please [edit] and additional information direction into the question - don't add as comments.

Comment: Are you trying to compare the values on the database side in SQL, or on the client side in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine date part and time part into single datetime like this:

```cs
var time = TimeSpan.Parse("15:30:00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var date = DateTime.Parse("2020-01-01", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var dateTime = date.Add(time);

if (DateTime.Now > dateTime)
{
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend doing this in the database query instead @HaythamAbdElghany.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue at the source and introduce a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[whatever]
(
    [that_day] CHAR(10) NULL, 
    [that_time] CHAR(8) NULL, 
    [day_time] AS TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, that_day + ' ' + that_time) 
)
```

However this should only be the first step and fix the anti-pattern of storing date and time information as text in your database.

Comment: thank you Filburt for your answer, but i don`t need update table in database i just want process it on the client side in C# and Nenad answer it helped , thanks any way